# Отслеживание обновления атрибута src у динамически добавляемого img

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

На странице динамически добавляются объекты `img` с классом `cell-image img-fluid` внутрь блока с id `photos`. Мне нужно отслеживать изменение атрибута 'src' у этих изображений. Я попробовал такой подход, который работает для события `click` у динамически добавляемых div-ов:

```
$('#photos').on('load',
    $('img[class="cell-image"]'),
    function() {
        alert("Ура");
    });
```

Однако он не работает в этом случае. Как заставить обработчик события реагировать?

Comment: Куда вам пригодится отслеживание атрибута `src`? Вы будете динамически обновлять его, или же где-то хранить, чтобы потом использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#photos').get(0).addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("cell-image"))
    console.log("Ура");
}, true);

function addImage() {
  $('#photos').append(
    "<img class='cell-image' src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png'/>"
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addImage()">Add Image</button>
<div id="photos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот. пример как отслеживать изменения атрибутов и других свойст объекта:
(Надеюсь что я понял вопрос)

```js
var target = document.getElementById('img-1');

// создаём экземпляр MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
    //слушаем изменения атрибута и вызываем алерт
    if (mutation.attributeName === "src") {
      alert('src');
    }
  });
});

// конфигурация нашего observer:
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: false,
  characterData: false
};

// передаём в качестве аргументов целевой элемент и его конфигурацию
observer.observe(target, config);


// test
setTimeout(() => {
  target.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1_webp_ll.png');
  // динамически можем добавлять этот слушатель например
  let newTarget = document.createElement('img');
  newTarget.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png')
  observer.observe(newTarget, config);
  document.body.append(newTarget);
  setTimeout(() => {
    newTarget.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1_webp_ll.png')
  }, 2000)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<img id="img-1" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png" />
```